# What's wrong with my API and how can I fix it if it's true

Tags: django-rest-framework, vuejs2, image-uploading

My viewset:

```
class UserViewSet(SerializerByActionMixin, LoggingMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializers = {
        'default': UserSerializer,
        'create': UserCreateSerializer,
        'update': UserUpdateSerializer,
    }

    def get_permissions(self):
        # allow non-authenticated user to create via POST
        return (AllowAny() if self.request.method == 'POST'
                else IsStaffOrTargetUser()),
```

My serializer for update:

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'mobile_phone',
            'avatar',
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, field, value)
        instance.save()
        log.info("User %s, %s changed his profile" % (instance.username, instance.email))
        return instance
```

Frontend in VueJs. 
I'm not very strong at Vue, but my partner writes that I can not upload the avatar to the file system, well, as I understand the form on the frontend does not load the image and does not save ... 
Tell me if I need to write a separate presentation and serializer for the avatar, or maybe I did not add some method? I'm not very experienced in DRF?
My thanks!